While con varios condicionates C#
Acabo de empezar a programar en C# y me he quedado atascado en un ejercicio sencillo aplicando un While.
El ejercicio básicamente es que el usuario elija 2 números y ver cuando coinciden con otros 2 números aleatorios elegidos por programa. La comparación estoy intentando hacerla con un While pero no consigo que funcione.
A ver si ustedes pueden ver el fallo, Gracias.
    /* JUEGO LOTERIA 2 NUMEROS - 2 NUMEROS DEL 0 AL 5 */
    Random numero = new Random();
    int aleatorio1 = numero.Next(0, 5);
    int aleatorio2 = numero.Next(0, 5);

    int intentos = 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido a la lotería, introduces 2 numeros del 0 al 5 y veremos en cuantos intentos coinciden con 2 números aleatorios");
    Console.WriteLine("Introduce el Primer Número");
    int minumero1 =int.Parse( Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Introduce el Segundo Número");
    int minumero2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


    while (minumero1 != aleatorio1 && minumero2 != aleatorio2)
    {
      Console.WriteLine($"Fallaste!, elegiste los números {minumero1},{minumero2} y los números aleatorios fueron {aleatorio1},{aleatorio2}. LlevaS {intentos} intentos");
      intentos++;
      aleatorio1 = numero.Next(0, 5);
      aleatorio2 = numero.Next(0, 5);
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Correcto! Elegiste los números {minumero1},{minumero2} y los números aleatorios fueron {aleatorio1},{aleatorio2} y ha necesitado {intentos} intentos");


Quieres la comparación, siempre? cuando coincidan? o como?

@Excorpion quiero que cuando el usuario haya introducido el valor de sus 2 números el programa compruebe si coinciden con los 2 números aleatorios, y sino coinciden que vaya modificando de forma random los valores aleatorios hasta que coincidan por los introducidos inicialmente por el usuario. Finalmente cuando hayan coincidido indique en consola cuántas veces han tenido que cambiar los números aleatorios para que coincidieran. Espero se haya entendido.

Me resulta confuso, que dentor del bucle, informes por consola en cada iteracion que -fallaste la apuesta-, y cuales son los numeros y los aleatorios. ¿Este programa debe pedir 2 numeros/apuesta en cada nuevo intento/creacion de aleatorios o no?

Según lo indicado en el comentario:
Queremos que se sigan generando números, hasta coincidir con los ingresador por el usuario.
Para eso vamos a modificar primeramente el while. Este tiene una comprobación AND (&&), lo que buscamos es un OR (||), para que evalúe uno y el otro por separado.
int intentos = 0; //Los contadores es mejor iniciarlos en 0
//Cambiamos la comprobación, ya que no buscamos ambos a la vez, es uno o el otro
while (aleatorio1 != minumero1 || aleatorio2 != minumero2)
{
    intentos++;
    aleatorio1 = numero.Next(0, 5);
    aleatorio2 = numero.Next(0, 5);
    Console.WriteLine($"Intento {intentos}: Los números aleatorios son {aleatorio1},{aleatorio2}. No coinciden con {minumero1},{minumero2}.");
}

// Cuando coincidan
Console.WriteLine($"¡Correcto! Los números aleatorios {aleatorio1},{aleatorio2} coinciden con tus números {minumero1},{minumero2}.");
Console.WriteLine($"Los números aleatorios tuvieron que cambiar {intentos} veces para que coincidieran.");


Muchisimas gracias, tengo que repasar mi lógica, no sabes la de rato que le había dedicado a este problema y tan solo es que había elegido mal la puerta lógica. Ahora lo hace perfecto, de nuevo muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

A veces sucede, hay que desconectarse para volver a pensar en el problema. Suerte.

Recordemos que: si lo que está dentro del while es true la iteración se ejecuta y si es false se detiene
Ahora un ejemplo, digamos que tienes:

minumero1=1
minumero2=2
aleatorio1=1
aleatorio2=3

minumero1 != aleatorio1 && minumero2 != aleatorio2
    1     !=      1     &&     2     !=     3
    \            /              \          /  
     \          /                \        /
         false          &&          true
           \                         /  
            \                       /
                      false

Es decir, tal como tienes la condición basta acertar un solo número para que el while se detenga.
Es bastante habitual enredarse con las condiciones, para mi siempre ha sido más fácil ver todo en positivo y luego de ser necesario negarlo, por ejemplo tu dices

mientras NO se cumpla que minumero1 es igual a aleatorio1 y minumero2 igual a aleatorio2

Esto se traduce como
 ! (minumero1 == aleatorio1 && minumero2 == aleatorio2)

La negación cambia los operadores a su contrario, por lo que de arriba es igual a:
Se cambia el == por != y el && por ||
 minumero1 != aleatorio1 || minumero2 != aleatorio2)

Otra forma de realizar lo mismo es con tuplas, quedando como
while( (minumero1,minumero2) != (aleatorio1, aleatorio2) )


Pero, todas las alternativas anteriores tienen el mismo problema: que pasa si tu par de números es 2,1 y los aleatorios son 1,2. Tienes los mismos números, solo que en distinto orden
Aquí puedes anidar más condicionales implementando todas las permutaciones posibles, pero y que pasa si en lugar de ser 2 número que hay que elegir son 10. Tenemos que escribir condiciones hasta aburrirnos. Como no somos animales, podemos usar lista y aprovecha la función Intersect para preguntar por la intersección de 2 listas (o conjuntos). Si la intersección tiene la misma cantidad de elementos que lo original es que son todos iguales:
Random numero = new Random();
int aleatorio1 = numero.Next(0, 5);
int aleatorio2 = numero.Next(0, 5);

int intentos = 1;
Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido a la lotería, introduces 2 numeros del 0 al 5 y veremos en cuantos intentos coinciden con 2 números aleatorios");
Console.WriteLine("Introduce el Primer Número");
int minumero1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()!);
Console.WriteLine("Introduce el Segundo Número");
int minumero2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()!);
        
int[] numeros = [minumero1,minumero2];
int[] aleatorios = [aleatorio1, aleatorio2];

while (numeros.Intersect(aleatorios).Count() != numeros.Length)
{

    Console.WriteLine($"Fallaste!, elegiste los números {minumero1},{minumero2} y los números aleatorios fueron {aleatorios[0]},{aleatorios[1]}. LlevaS {intentos} intentos");
    intentos++;
    aleatorios = [numero.Next(0, 5), numero.Next(0, 5)];

}

Console.WriteLine($"Correcto! Elegiste los números {minumero1},{minumero2} y los números aleatorios fueron {aleatorios[0]},{aleatorios[1]} y ha necesitado {intentos} intentos");



Todos los días se aprende algo. La verdad es que se ve mucho más claro pensando el While en positivo y luego negarlo todo.  Ademas no sabia que al negarlo el AND se convirtía en OR. Lo de la lista me lo apunto para otro ejercicio que estoy haciendo y me viene muy bien. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

La generacion de Nºs aleatorios esta fuera del bucle, de modo que si no acierta a la primera, siendo el algoritmo adecuado, se volveria un bucle infinito, y se quedaria pillado aqui el programa, grapado.
Para ver cuantos intentos harian falta para una sola apuesta (2 numeros del 0 al 5, por ejecucion del programa), tienes que meter la creacion de aleatorios dentro del bucle, y arreglar el bucle adecuadamente para que reitere mientras no coincidan los dos.
Yo este bucle en lugar de un While lo pondria Do { } While();
Ten en cuenta que tu codigo pide numeros del 0 al 5, pero no verifica que el numero de la apuesta sea efectivamente del 0 al 5 antes de proceder a realizar la comparación.
Para tener 1 sobre 5 oportunidades de acertar por numero/apuesta e intento, debe ser efectivamente un numero de 0 al 5, igual que el rango aleatorio al que apuestas.
Sino, las probabilidades de acertar, fuera del rango son del 0%. .. deja de ser posible, y se crea bucle infinito (.. doble error de bucle infinito) .. y aqui entonces se cuelga tambien el programa, grapado.
Porque y el conteo de intentos/probabilidades con apuestas fuera del rango aleatorio (0-5) nunca jamas va poder concidir, asi que no saldra
nunca del bucle.
Yo usaria esto ...
    /* JUEGO LOTERIA 2 NUMEROS - 2 NUMEROS DEL 0 AL 5 */
        int aleatorio1=-1;
        int aleatorio2=-1;
        int minumero1 =-1;
        int minumero2 = -1;
            Random numero = new Random();
             int intentos = 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Bienvenido a la lotería, introduces 2 numeros del 0 al 5 y veremos en cuantos intentos coinciden con 2 números aleatorios");
         
Do{
        Console.WriteLine("Introduce el Primer Número");
            minumero1 =int.Parse( Console.ReadLine());
        }While(minumero1<0 && minumero1 > 5);
         
        Do {
            Console.WriteLine("Introduce el Segundo Número");
           minumero2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }While(minumero2<0 && minumero2 > 5);

        Do {
         aleatorio1 = numero.Next(0, 5);
          aleatorio2 = numero.Next(0, 5);
         
        
         
          if  (minumero1 != aleatorio1 || minumero2 != aleatorio2)
        {  
        Console.WriteLine($"Fallaste!, elegiste los números {minumero1},{minumero2} y los números aleatorios fueron {aleatorio1},{aleatorio2}. LlevaS {intentos} intentos");
              intentos++;
        }
        else
    Console.WriteLine($"Correcto! Elegiste los números {minumero1},{minumero2} y los números aleatorios fueron {aleatorio1},{aleatorio2} y ha necesitado {intentos} intentos");
    
          
        }While(minumero1 != aleatorio1 ||minumero2 != aleatorio2);

